# Why has this needed folder become a submodule?

Tags: django, windows, git, github, git-submodules

I have a folder which has all the main code in it but its been created on Github as a submodule and I don't know how to change it or why it was created that way by Git?

Also I'm making new branches and pushing them and every time I do the same "branch" (it seems) is being pushed so the folder is staying the same.

```
git branch new
git add .
git commit -m "blah"
git remote add origin new
```

I take it that this code is wrong to make a completely new branch commit?

I've tried numerous ways and seem to be going down a dead end constantly. Is there something wrong with my commits or adds?

Comment: That is correct. Did you do a `git submodule add` at some point? Do you have a .gitmodules file? You could try `git submodule deinit -f <path>`

Comment: I definitely didnt do submodule add which is weird. I also dont have any gitmodules files. Thank you for the deinit. It looks to have helped. Can i recommit that folder after?

Comment: Should be fine to commit